# How to check, input text is empty and should throw an error msg if text is empty, error should gone while entering in to the text?

Tags: input

I have input textbox, I want to show an error when it is empty and cross text maxlength limit i.e 30,

the error msg should not display when user starts entering into the text.

Please enter a maximum of 30 characters.

Comment: What platform? Amiga? System 7? NEXTStep? System/360?

Comment: I'm using angularjs